# Macros and multi-line comments

Tags: c++, macros

I need to have multi-line comments within a group of macros so that one of the macros initiates a comment block and another concludes it, like this:

```
#define C_BEGIN /*
#define C_END */
... other macros
```

But sure enough, this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Comments are ignored even before macros are replaced. Why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: Why not just use comments to begin with?

Comment: Where would you need to use this that you can't use conditional compilation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do it for the following reasoning. Let's assume it *is* possible.

So you created a macro that replaces itself with `/*`, and another for `*/`. What happens then? First, the comments are removed from the code. After that, the preprocessor replaces your macros with the comments. After that, the compiler will choke: it doesn't know what to do with `/*` and `*/` because it simply never faces such things: the comments are *always* delete before the compilation, so it doesn't even know what a "comment" is. It will probably think it's a division followed by multiplication.

So our assumption is wrong and you can't do it.

Comment: Well, `/*` _could_ be legal. Let's say you have `float a, *b`; and want to do `a / *b` -- in _that_ case, it's legal. (This doesn't invalidate your answer at all, though -- it's still not a comment, and still won't be treated as such, and if you tried to write it as `/*` in your source code you'd get an error for an unended comment)

Answer (score 5):

Comment processing happens before macro expansion:

> [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
>
> #### 2.2 Phases of translation [lex.phases]
>
> 1 - The precedence among the syntax rules of translation is speciﬁed by the following phases. [...]
>     3. [...] Each comment is replaced by one space character. [...]
>     4. Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded [...]

Perhaps you could try preprocessing your source file twice? (Note: don't do this.)

Answer (score 2):

> But sure enough, this approach doesn't work.

It can't work. The comment in your `#define C_BEGIN` is not a part of and cannot be a part of your macro definition. As far as the language is concerned, your `#define C_END` is not a macro definition. It just a part of that multiline comment. In other words, it is whitespace. Comments are processed (turned into whitespace) before the preprocessor / compiler gets to the stage of interpreting your macro definitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE, you can simply press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> for Windows or <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> on Mac. You should select the lines you want to comment first.